# ViewSet use Token Authentication at only one REST operation (Django Rest)

Tags: django-rest-framework

**Problem**

I am using Django Rest Framework. In that case a `ViewSet`. Only on one REST operation I want to use `Token Authentication`. Does DRF provide even provide something like that ?

Thank your for your help.

```
 class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
      serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

      #Here the Token Authentication should be
      def destroy(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
          try:
              user = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
              user.delete()
          except User.DoesNotExist:
              return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
          return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override the **`get_authenticators()`** method as below.The `get_authenticators()` method instantiates and returns the list of authenticators that this view can use.In your case, the method will return/validate the **`TokenAuthentication`** if the action is ***destroy***, (`HTTP DELETE`)

```
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication


class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # your code
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    def get_authenticators(self):
        if self.action == 'destroy':
            return super().get_authenticators()
        return []

    def destroy(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
        # your code
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to be correct. I will try it later. Can you explain why I should use permission classes instead of authentication classes ? Why can‘t I override the authentication classes like the permission classes ? It seems more logical to me. It would be very nice if you could add that explanation to your answer.

Comment: It was a logical error from my side :( Anyway I've updated the answer :)

Comment: Thank you. Now everything makes Sense :)

Comment: Happy to help you :)

Comment: The problem  with that solution is that at that point action is not defined yet at least for drf  3

Answer (score 1):

A way can be define a custom permission class for that something like this:

```
class AuthenticatedDelete(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.method == 'DELETE':
            if not request.user.is_authenticated():
                return False
        return True
```

And then add it to your `permission_classes`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your first approach is not possible because it only can be used with @apiview. Second one looks promising.

Comment: @Coder949 are you sure about first approach? Base on docs it should work, I would examine that asap.

Comment: I am sure. I tried it and it does not work. In the docs also is said `Or, if you're using the @api_view decorator with function based views.`. Because of that I conclude that it only works together with @api_view decorator.

Comment: Or didn't mean together, I worked with it on class based api and it worked fine, but I didn't examine decorating on method of class